# Discovery Service - Normalize JSON input field into date data type

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

Created a Machine Learning Model using Watson Knowledge studio and deployed same into Watson Discovery successfully. Also, able to perform basic queries.

One of my requirement is to query for particular date range. For this, I need to normalize a JSON field into date data type.Unable to find a way to Normalize date data type( As web page might represent dates in different formats).

Below is the sample JSON, that contain date.

```
"entities": [
    {
        "count": 1,
        "sentiment": {
        "type": "neutral",
        "mixed": false
        },
        "text": "December 12, 2013",
        "type": "Date"
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "sentiment": {
        "score": 0.454514,
        "type": "positive",
        "mixed": false
        },
        "text": "$100 Million",
        "type": "Fine"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Watson Discovery Service does not currently have a way to manipulate/parse the dates at ingestion time, you will be to perform this normalization before ingesting into the service.  (I am an IBM Employee)